# About enveloping algebras of direct sums

Tags: lie-algebras

Let us consider a $R$-Lie algebra ($R$ is a commutative ring) written as a (module) direct sum of two of its subalgebras
$$
\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus\mathfrak{g}_2
$$ 
and the natural mapping 
$$
\alpha : \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes_R\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_2)\to\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})
$$
($\mathfrak{g}_i$ are not necessarily ideals).

It is trivial, using PBW theorem that, if the ground ring $R$ is a field, $\alpha$ is one-to-one.

What is true/known in the general case ?

**Late update** Question [exported to MO.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300851/about-enveloping-algebras-of-direct-sums)